Use a list ouput of a Python function as input of another function
I use the follwing Python code:
a, b, c = foo()
res = foo2(a, b, c)

I would like to write instead:
res = foo2(foo())

but it doesn't work: the output of foo is regarded as the first argument of foo2.
Isn't there a way not to create those 3 useless variables?

Use: foo2(*foo()).  If you want to research it, it’s called unpacking.  Docs reference.

Although I knew what to look for, except for the name, I spent too many minutes looking for the * in the language reference and docs, in vain. I think a documentation overhaul, maybe also with SEO in mind, would be beneficial for Python.

Great, s3dev. Thanks to you
